# Numerical calculation on string with currency in RobotFramework

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to remove the currency symbol from a string so that i can do some calculation in my robot test

```
  # .  ${PD_RT} value is $47.89

  ${price_rt} =  get text  ${PD_RT}
  ${final_price} =  evaluate  ${price_rt} *10 / 100
```

Comment: do you know for certain that `${price_rt}` is a single dollar value with one leading dollar sign? Or do you need something that can pick up a number from a much longer string?

Comment: max value will be in three characters $290.89.So i need to pick up only number value to perform calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the currency sign from the string, using the keyword `Remove String` from the String library, and convert the result to a float.

```
${final_price}=     Remove String   ${price_rt}        $
${final_price}=     Convert To Number   ${final_price}
${final_price}=     Evaluate   ${final_price} * 10/100
```

Thus if the sign is not the first character, it'll still work; if the string cannot be casted to float, there will be an error message:
`final_price_value cannot be converted to a floating point number`

Comment: this is almost working for me but only issue is after evaluate it is returning value like 5.658 and i want to round it up to 2 decimal points like 5.67. i tried to using round but it returning value 6.

Comment: `${final_price}=    Evaluate    round(${final_price}, 2)` should do it; the `2` argument is the precision - 2 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

If you know with absolute certainty that the variable contains a number with a single leading dollar sign, you can use robot's extended variable syntax to remove that character while leveraging robot's method of doing variable substitution when calling evaluate.

Example:

```
${final_price}=  evaluate  ${price_rt[1:]}  * 10 / 100
```

This works because robot will first evaluate `price_rt[1:]` as if it were a string, and then pass the resulting characters to `evaluate`. `evaluate` will then see that raw string as a number, and perform the calculation.

Of course, this will fail if `${price_rt}` doesn't contain one character followed by a valid number.

Comment: getting this error while executing the code :ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: @user6406388: then I would have to say that `${price_rt}` is not actually a string that begins with a dollar sign and has a number following it. Try logging `${price_rt}` right before the statement that gives you the error. Like I said in the answer, this will only work if you know with absolute certainty that the value matches the expected pattern.